# Passing tuple to a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-multithreading

In the following code:

```
def fun(args, **kwargs):
    print(len(args))

thread = threading.Thread(
    target=fun, args=('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'), kwargs={'sep': ' & '})

thread.start()
```

I am trying to pass a tuple to the parameter `args` but it gives the following error:

`TypeError: fun() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

But when I use args=`(('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'),)` it works. I understand that it is considered as a tuple but why `('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')` is not being considered as a tuple?

Comment: What makes you think that `('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')` is not being considered as a tuple? _Read the error message carefully_, it says what the actual problem is quite clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are passing a tuple as `Thread`'s `args` parameter.  In the second case you are passing a tuple *containing a tuple as its first entry*.

```py
len(
  ('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')
) # 3

len(
  (('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'))
) # 1
```

The `args` parameter of `threading.Thread` is splatted into `target`'s call (so each argument in the iterable passed to `args` is unpacked into a separate argument for `target`):

```py
threading.Thread(target=fun, args=('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'))
# is equivalent to (but in another thread)
fun(*('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'))
# which is equivalent to
fun('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')
```

compared to:

```py
threading.Thread(target=fun, args=(('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'),))
# is equivalent to (but in another thread)
fun(*(('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'),))
# which is equivalent to
fun(('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'))
```

Comment: Why is it getting splatted to fun(*('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')) and why not fun(('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers'))? Is it because Thread() is designed to do it that way?

Comment: If `args=('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Tigers')` was passed as a _single_ argument to `fun`, how would you pass _two_ positional arguments to `def add(x, y): pass`?  `Thread(target=add, args=# what goes here?)`